# Recover deleted files using foremost

Tags: data-recovery

In the foremost manual it says that it can be used to *recover files using their headers, footers and data structures*. Since file deletion does not actually erase data and data is still there until some other data overwrites it. Hence I tried to recover my video files (mp4 format) just after deleting it (files were in external drive). But it just created the *mp4* folder and ran for near about half an hour but couldn't recover even one of the file (there were total of 20 video files).

The command I used was:

```
foremost -t mp4 .
```

I ran it inside the directory where the files were already present.

How can I recover those files? Any other effective method would also be encouraged.

Comment: TestDisk is excellent at recovering deleted files, sometimes with their original filenames, it could even browse all the files (regular and deleted) and allow copying just a few chosen ones. Or PhotoRec can search only free space & copy deleted/lost files too, with terminal/ascii gui menus and a constantly updated progress status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foremost` needs access to the device containing the files, not the directory where it is mounted. In your case, assuming your external drive (and appropriate partition) ends up being `/dev/sdc1`, you'd make sure it's unmounted and run

```
foremost -t mp4 /dev/sdc1
```

You need to run this from a directory with enough room to store the recovered files.

Since it's a NTFS filesystem, you could try `ntfsundelete` instead (in the `ntfs-3g` package usually).

Comment: Thanks. But running it on a 1TB drive does not seem a good option I think. Would you suggest some other method in this case then?

Comment: Why not? Forensics specialists routinely run it on multi-terabyte devices... What filesystem does your external drive use?

Comment: NTFS file system. Also how much time do you think it will take to run `foremost` completely

Comment: You could use `ntfsundelete` then. I don't know how long it would take `foremost` to run, since you're specifying the file type it should pretty much run as fast as the disk can be read.

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish: Running `ntfsundelete`on a 1TB NTFS volume would take anywhere from 3 to 5 hours depending on yr hw and configuration specifics. Just make sure the recovery setup is UPS-powered. If it crashes for any reason, yr erased volume won't be hurt and you can later resume yr recovery from the last inode where a file was successfully recovered.